# Onedrive For Business- Sharing file

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, onedrive

I set-up one iOS app in Azure Portal to integrate with OneDrive for business.

In "Permission to other app" we selected all permission for - Microsoft Graph - Office 365 SharePoint online - Window Azure Active Directory

I run iOS sample code in SDK and it works for almost functions except for "Share file".

Error: 403 "forbidden" UserInfo={error=notAllowed: The feature has been disabled. Please contact your admin to get it enable., NSLocalizedDescription=forbidden}

Maybe I missed any configuration somewhere?

Comment: Are you attempting to generate an anonymous sharing link?

Comment: Yes, we share by anonymous sharing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to enable external sharing as described in the following link
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US